# Getting data in List into DataGrid ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I am having trouble getting items from a list to a combobox column in a datagrid in WPF. This is new to me so any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems there are many ways to do it but I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

'''

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Positionname}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="poscombo Loaded="comboposloaded"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

List with Data in the code behind

```
 List<Positions> PositionList = new List<Positions>();
```

**UPDATE:
I ended up adding a  loading event to pull the list as the itemsource. The question now is how to get the selected value from combobox back into the text block?**

C# Added to get combo loaded.

```
    private void comboposloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        cmb.ItemsSource = PositionList;
        cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "info";
        cmb.SelectedValuePath = "psnme";

    }
```

Comment: Use data binding. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question now is how to get the selected value from combobox back into the text block?

Bind the `psnme` property of the `Positions` object to the `Positionname` property of the data object:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="poscombo" Loaded="comboposloaded"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Positionname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data binding for DataGridComboBoxColumn looks a little more complicated than you might think.

1. Use ObservableCollection instead of List. This will automatically update the content of the DataGrid.
2. You can load data into a combo box using ObjectDataProvide. This will also ensure that the data in the source is automatically updated.
   Here's a working example.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public EmployeeViewModel EmployeeVM;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EmployeeVM = new EmployeeViewModel();
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = EmployeeVM.EmployeeList;
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PositionEnum Position { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PositionEnum { Marketeer, Mechanic, Accountant };
    public class EmployeeViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList =
          new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        public EmployeeViewModel()
        { 
            EmployeeList.Add(new Employee()
             { Name = "James Smith", Position = PositionEnum.Accountant });
            EmployeeList.Add(new Employee()
             { Name = "Robert Johnson", Position = PositionEnum.Marketeer });
            EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() 
             { Name = "David Williams", Position = PositionEnum.Mechanic });
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Create list of enumeration values-->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type Type="local:PositionEnum"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"      
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            RowHeaderWidth="0" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                   Binding="{Binding Name}"
                   Header="Name" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    Header="Order Status"
                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Position}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Think you need to familiarize yourself with the MVVM pattern and use that as a basis for building such applications.